# GORM grails withCriteria query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 3 domain:
1) user
2) profile
3) Doctor

1) doctor extends user
2) user hasOne profile

```
class User {
    String username
    String password
    static hasOne = [profile: Profile]
}

class Profile {
    String fullName
    String address
    String cellno
}

class Doctor {
    String workLocation
    String specialization
}
```

How do I write a GORM query to list all the doctor based on specialization and `workLocation` with their names `profile.fullName`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Doctor` extends `User`, I'm assuming the `Doctor` domain class looks like this:

```
class Doctor extends User {
    String workLocation
    String specialization
}
```

You can get a list of `Doctor` instances with a GORM query like this:

```
def location = 'someWorkLocation'
def spec = 'someSpecialization'

def doctors = Doctor.withCriteria {
    eq 'specialization', spec
    eq 'workLocation', location
}.list()
```

The query above uses the `eq()` method to specify the [*WHERE*](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/) criteria. If you want the full names rather that `Doctor` instances you'll need a projection:

```
def names = doctors.withCriteria {
    eq 'specialization', spec
    eq 'workLocation', location

    projections {
        profile {
            property 'fullName'
        }
    }
}
```

The projection is essentially the [*SELECT*](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/) part of the query.